# I just need one line of Regex code edited

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

the following code works but how can it be edited to only detect the first curly brace after an end parenthesis?

```
'/\{(([^{}]*|(?R))*)\}/'
```

Example:

```
if (1==1) 
{ 
echo "testing {$username}"; 
}
```

The problem is that it detects ALL curly brackets, even the one surrounding the $username variable.  So I think a solution would be to detect is there is a ) before the first curly bracket.  I tried about 20 different things myself but cannot get it to work.  How can it be edited to only detect ) {  Oh and please add code if there are spaces and tabs involved inbetween the first curly bracket and end parenthesis if that matters.  Thanks.

Comment: Before going into detail, what is the goal you try to achieve? If you want to parse PHP code -- which is what it looks to me -- i would recommend to use the PHP tokenizer instead of trying to build something with regexp: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php -- if this is not useful to you, i would recommend writing a tokenizer on my own, anyway ... parsing a programming language can get very ugly, if you want to do it with simple regexps

Comment: Thanks but everything works perfectly and is in place I just need that line edited instead of going into a whole new direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\)\s*\{
```

as part of your pattern to detect simple cases like your example. Note that you can't use a positive lookbehind of variable length though, so you can't alter it to (?<=)\s*){

My pattern will still pick up code that is commented out though, and won't detect code that has a comment between the ) and the {. You wouldn't want to use a regex to try to detect such cases.